# resize handles around an image implementation

Tags: java, resize, libgdx, draggable, transformation

Similar to [Resizing Handles on a Rotated Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366892/resizing-handles-on-a-rotated-element), I'm implementing a way for the user to scale an Image through handles in `libGDX`. A problem I keep bumping into is the scaling of the Image. I currently use [`Scene2D`](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d) which I used to create a `Group` which contains the Image and 8 handles around the Image. The positions of the handles are defined relative to the Image. This works fine for rotation and translation, but not for scaling. When the `Group` gets rescaled, so does the handle. But because of the scaling, the offset between the handle and the image is not the same anymore. I hacked around a bit to be able to draw the handles at the correct place even with scaling. But the problem is the bounds of the Handles. This is important for the mouse to be able to select the correct region (which is also a rectangle). After setting the bounds, these are transformed and the scaling messes with the handle's size and location. Is using a `Group` a dead end? Are there better ways to handle this problem?

In short: I want handles to be placed around an Image to rescale it. The handle's position has to move correctly with any transformation on the Image and the handle's size has to remain intact.

A solution might be to avoid the scaling by resizing the width and height yourself. This however doesn't scale the `Actors` within the `Group` as you would expect.

[image: example representation of resize handles]

Comment: the best I can come up with is to take the four corners points and transform them from localToStage and use those points to figure out the width, height, rotation and scaling of the image. Then you can draw those handles directly on top of the screen.